# Surprising pattern of big primes in a derivative series

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, taylor-expansion

A pattern of large prime numbers appeared where I was not expecting one, and I'm fascinated to know why.  I needed to calculate the Taylor Series for

$$f(x)\equiv\ln\left(e^{(x+1)^{2}}+e^{(x-1)^{2}}\right)$$

Because the function is even, the odd derivatives wrt x are obviously zero.  But the even derivatives all have the form of $2^n *$(several large primes).  For example:

$\left(\frac{d^{20}f}{dx^{20}}\right)_{x=0}=2^{37}*31*41*283*617$

$\left(\frac{d^{50}f}{dx^{50}}\right)_{x=0}=2^{98}*31*251*601*1801*4051*417202699*47464429777438199$

$\left(\frac{d^{100}f}{dx^{100}}\right)_{x=0}=2^{197}*31*41*251*263*379*601*1801*4051*8101*268501*28717943*65677171692755556482181133*503175397608024323584539371320514986481668897$

The powers of 2 are almost but not quite monotonically increasing, and the large primes are widely spaced but certain ones appear often, like 1801 and 4051 in the examples above.

I realize this is a vague question, but I'm perplexed as to why a pattern of primes like this would appear.  Any ideas?

Here is some Mathematica code to generate the results. It's not great MMa code because I wrote it to be readable to non-users of MMa.

```
ord = 25;  (* Number of even derivatives to calculate *)
f[x] := Exp[(x + 1)^2] + Exp[(x - 1)^2];
deriv = Table[0, {j, 1, ord}]; (* Initialize an empty table *)
deriv[[1]] = D[Log[f[x]], {x, 2}];
Do[deriv[[j]] = D[deriv[[j - 1]], {x, 2}] // Together, {j, 2, ord}]; (* Calc the derivatives *)
coef = deriv /. x -> 0; (* Evaluate the derivatives at x=0 *)
factors = Table[FactorInteger[Abs[coef[[i]]]], {i, 1, ord}]; (* Prime-factorize all the coefs *)
Do[Print[2*i, "th deriv = ", Abs[coef[[i]]], " -> ", factors[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[coef]}];
```

Comment: I suppose what you're getting at is that the value of the derivative is the product of a power of two and a square-free number?

Comment: $$\begin{align}
\log\left(e^{(x+1)^2}+e^{(x-1)^2}\right) &= x^2 + 1 +\log (2) +\log\left(\frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{2}\right)\\ 
&= x^2+1+\log 2+\log\cosh 2x
\end{align}$$ Which probably explains the powers of $2$.

Comment: Higher order derivatives, of course, eliminate $x^2+1+\log 2$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Yes, "square-free" is a way you could put it. It was more the big primes that surprised me.

Comment: But it does mean that you are dealing with a much similar function, since the first derivative of $\log \cosh 2x$ is $2\tanh 2x$, so those primes are coming from derivatives of $\tanh x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  Fair point.  I have re-titled the Question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   Also, yes, I see your point that I could have stated this problem as "Big Primes in the expansion of Tanh[x]".  That would state more clearly the part I'm puzzled about (because the 2^n thing wouldn't be there) but it happened that I came upon this puzzle while looking at expansions of the Gaussian Mixture.

Answer (score 1):

See OEIS sequence [A000182](https://oeis.org/A000182).  There are a number of interesting patterns.
For odd primes $p$ it appears that (the signed version) $a(n)$ is periodic mod $p$ with period $(p-1)/2$.
If so, then e.g. none of these numbers $a(n)$ are divisible by 
$3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 19, 23$ or $29$, but $a(n)$ is divisible by $17$ iff $n$ is divisible by $4$ but not by $8$, and by 
by $31$ if $n$ is divisible by $5$ but not by $15$.

I suspect these can be deduced from the recurrence relation
$$a(n) = (-1)^{n-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{n-i+1}{2 n-1 \choose 2 i-1} a(i)$$

Comment: Robert, you just gave another of your trademark Extremely Dense Answers that I couldn't quite understand.  Could you please expand, explain, and expound that just a bit more?  Thanks.    :-)